# How can I convert a number based on the kilo?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function

I have a table like this:

```
// table
+----+--------+------------+
| id |  name  | reputation |
+----+--------+------------+
| 1  | jack   | 534431     |
| 2  | peter  | 334        |
| 3  | amos   | 1300       |
| 4  | carter | 13490      |
| 5  | basil  | 1351       |
+----+--------+------------+
```

Now I want to convert the value of `reputation` to a number based on the kilo. Currently I do that by SQL. Like this:

```
SELECT id, name,
    CASE WHEN value >= 1000 THEN
         CONCAT(TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM SUBSTR(TRUNCATE(number/1000, 1), 1, 4)), 'k')
         ELSE value
    END as reputation
FROM `table`
```

Yes it works, I want to know how can I do that by PHP? I guess doing by that would be more flexible and faster. Well is there any PHP function?

---

**EDIT:** Here is the output of query above:

```
// newtable
+----+--------+------------+
| id |  name  | reputation |
+----+--------+------------+
| 1  | jack   | 534k       |
| 2  | peter  | 334        |
| 3  | amos   | 1.3k       |
| 4  | carter | 13.4k      |
| 5  | basil  | 1.3k       |
+----+--------+------------+
```

Comment: What does that sql output?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I've added it into my question.

Comment: Downvoter may you please tell me why?

Comment: There's no php function and you should write it yourself.

Comment: Why do you need it to be faster? Do you have speed issues? The MySQL code you posted should execute extremely fast.

Comment: @u_mulder Ah ok, just do you think doing that by PHP is better or SQL ?

Comment: @Jocelyn No there isn't any problem. I just like to improve it .. And I guess doing that by PHP is better.

Comment: Mostly what can be done in SQL should be done there. But you can write tests and compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reason you might be opting to do it PHP is that it will give some flexibility when you want to show some other value like M(for million), or maybe show different suffix for each level of value e.g when you are in thousands you show K, and in millions you show M.

Here is some code which you can use in PHP to do that:

```
function getPrettyNumber($n) {
        if($n>=1000000000000) return round(($n/1000000000000),1).'T';
        else if($n>=1000000000) return round(($n/1000000000),1).'B';
        else if($n>=1000000) return round(($n/1000000),1).'M';
        else if($n>=1000) return round(($n/1000),1).'K';

        return number_format($n);
}
```

use of `round()` with 1 as second parameter is optional.
You can easily modify the above code to fit your use case.

Answer (score 0):

The best **solution**:

```
function getPrettyNumber($n) {
    if     ( $n < 10000 )     return $n;
    elseif ( $n < 100000 )    return round( $n / 1000, 1) . "k";
    elseif ( $n < 1000000 )   return floor( $n / 1000 )   . "k";
    elseif ( $n < 1000000000) return floor( $n / 1000000) . "M";
    else                      return "Wow!!!";      
}
```

Also here is some **examples**:

```
1        => 1
10       => 10
100      => 100
1000     => 1000
1001     => 1001
10000    => 10k
10100    => 10.1k
100000   => 100k
101000   => 101k
101111   => 101k
1000000  => 1M
1111111  => 1M
10111111 => 10M
11000000 => 11M
```